# How to get / watch for a Debian bug update for Ubuntu in initramfs-tools 0.122ubuntu8.8

Tags: ubuntu, debian, keyboard-layout, initramfs-tools

On installing a recent Xubuntu with Ubuntu 16.04, I find myself unable to set keyboard layout permanently to German becase every time I do it using dpkg, the [initramfs-tools bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/initramfs-tools/+bug/1667512) kicks in.

```
dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration
```

and then the error message about initramfs-tools appears.

Now luckily I know that there is a [merge request](https://salsa.debian.org/kernel-team/initramfs-tools/commit/48cfe9cf2928e639e418336c2faa317d050090c3) submitted for this bug.

How will I know that the patch has become available? (i.e. how do I know that the next version of initramfs made for Debian has made its way into the Ubuntu update site?) Because, the Ubuntu bug page says "Status: fix released" but this is obviously not enough.

And.. is there a workoaround for time being?

Answer (score 0):

Solved:

- search for the bug numer in this case 1667512 in the [changelog](https://launchpad.net/debian/+source/initramfs-tools/+changelog) of the package

So, now I know that I need to look for initramfs-tools from version 0.131.

Finally, the [Ubuntu packages site](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=initramfs-tools) gives me an overview of which distribution have which version (currently, Ubuntu Cosmic 18.10).